# MySQL - Using If Then Else in MySQL UPDATE or SELECT Queries

Tags: mysql

How do I update a table and set different values upon the condition evaluating to True.

For instance :

```
UPDATE Table
SET A = '1' IF A > 0 AND A < 1
SET A = '2' IF A > 1 AND A < 2
WHERE A IS NOT NULL;
```

I have seen CASE expression and IF expression in Procedures and Functions but I want to use it in a simple update/select statement. Is it possible or am I expecting too much from this lovely open source database?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
UPDATE table
SET A = IF(A > 0 AND A < 1, 1, IF(A > 1 AND A < 2, 2, A))
WHERE A IS NOT NULL;
```

you might want to use `CEIL()` if `A` is always a floating point value `> 0` and `<= 2`

Comment: Values of A are just examples. I want to apply it to any condition. For instance : IF A IS NOT NULL SET to 'Some Varchar Value' ELSE SET to 'Some Other Varchar Value'; I will give your solution a shot and see how it works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 38):

Whilst you certainly *can* use MySQL's [`IF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) control flow function [as demonstrated by dbemerlin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2177630), I suspect it might be a little clearer to the reader (i.e. yourself, and any future developers who might pick up your code in the future) to use a [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) expression instead:

```
UPDATE Table
SET    A = CASE
         WHEN A > 0 AND A < 1 THEN 1
         WHEN A > 1 AND A < 2 THEN 2
         ELSE A
       END
WHERE  A IS NOT NULL
```

Of course, in this specific example it's a little wasteful to set `A` to itself in the `ELSE` clause—better entirely to filter such conditions from the `UPDATE`, via the `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE Table
SET    A = CASE
         WHEN A > 0 AND A < 1 THEN 1
         WHEN A > 1 AND A < 2 THEN 2
       END
WHERE  (A > 0 AND A < 1) OR (A > 1 AND A < 2)
```

(The inequalities entail `A IS NOT NULL`).

Or, if you want the intervals to be closed rather than open (note that this would set values of `0` to `1`—if that is undesirable, one could explicitly filter such cases in the `WHERE` clause, or else add a higher precedence `WHEN` condition):

```
UPDATE Table
SET    A = CASE
         WHEN A BETWEEN 0 AND 1 THEN 1
         WHEN A BETWEEN 1 AND 2 THEN 2
       END
WHERE  A BETWEEN 0 AND 2
```

Though, as dbmerlin also pointed out, for this specific situation you could consider using [`CEIL()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_ceil) instead:

```
UPDATE Table SET A = CEIL(A) WHERE A BETWEEN 0 AND 2
```

Comment: This is a much cleaner presentation and works universally even if there are more than two conditions. The `if()` statement solution offered by @dbemerlin requires nesting past two conditions, which will make the logic even harder to read and understand.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a query to update a table based on a comparison of another table. If record is not found in tableB, it will update the "active" value to "n". If it's found, will set the value to NULL

```
UPDATE tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.id = tableB.id
SET active = IF(tableB.id IS NULL, 'n', NULL)";
```

Hope this helps someone else.