# Update if else basic

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get a MySQL update done, which should be very easy, when the query runs if the value is 0 then it will be set to 1, if it is 1 then it will be set to 0.

```
update agents set manual_import = 0 if manual_import =1,set manual_import = 1 if manual_import = 1
```

There are so many examples on there but which one is the easiest?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - Using If Then Else in MySQL UPDATE or SELECT Queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177543/mysql-using-if-then-else-in-mysql-update-or-select-queries)

Answer (score 2):

A bit of math can help:

```
UPDATE agents
SET manual_import = 1 - manual_import       # turn 1 to 0 and 0 to 1
WHERE manual_import IN (0, 1)               # but only when the value is 0 or 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i have figured out this would be suitable for my own question and any other simple queries similar.

```
UPDATE agents SET manual_import = CASE
        WHEN manual_import = 1 THEN 0
        WHEN manual_import = 0 THEN 1    
        END
    WHERE a_id = $a_id
```

Comment: If `manual_import` takes more than just the values 0 and 1, this command would set any other value to `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using case when then

```
update agents set
manual_import = case when manual_import = 1 then 0 else 1
end
```

I assumed that manual_import has only two values 0 and 1 and if it has more than just 1 and 0 then try this:

```
    UPDATE agents SET manual_import = case
    when manual_import = 1 then 0
    when manual_import = 0 then 1  else manual_import   
    END
```

Answer (score -1):

In oracle database the esasiest way is the 'decode' function. As answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706100/mysql-equivalent-of-decode-function-in-oracle-and-intersystem-cache-database) question you can use the 'if' as following:

```
update agents set manual_import = if(manual_import=1,0,1)
```

Comment: If `manual_import` takes more than just the values 0 and 1, all values that aren't 1 (and not just 0) will become 1.