# MySQL If statement with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql

I want to write `IF` statement inside a `Stored procedure` in MySQL in the following way:

```
IF (exp1 and exp2 and exp3) or exp4
```

I know MySQL will treat `IF()` as a function call.
But I hope you got what I'm trying to achieve.
I am new to MySQL syntax.

Comment: Is it in a select statement or in a procedure?

Comment: @JorgeCampos It is inside a procedure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL - Using If Then Else in MySQL UPDATE or SELECT Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177543/mysql-using-if-then-else-in-mysql-update-or-select-queries)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In a procedure the use of an `IF` is pretty straight forward:

```
IF (yourCondition [logical operator(OR, AND) another condition] ) THEN
```

So in a practical example:

```
....
DECLARE m integer;
DECLARE n integer;
SET m = 1;
SET n = 0;
IF ((m>n AND m=1 AND n=0) OR m=n)THEN
     some code here
END IF;
```

The evaluation of the conditions follows the parenthesis rule same as in a mathematical operation.

You can refer to the [Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html)

Answer (score 2):

Another valid aproach:

if the validation is true **do this** is ejecuted.
if te validation is false, **do that** is ejecuted.

Note that the comma `,` is the separator in mysql.

```js
if((`something` = 'on' AND `other` = 'on' ),'do this', 'do that') AS `do_something_things`,
```

Comment: Doesn't work with the order, e.g. select * from item order by IF(@orientation=0, 'position / 1000, position % 1000', position)